# What am I doing wrong? (Trigonometric Identity)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\frac { \cos\theta  }{ 1-\sin\theta  } =\frac { \sin\theta -\csc\theta  }{ \cos\theta -\cot\theta  } $$

Steps I took:

$$\frac { \sin\theta -\frac { 1 }{ \sin\theta  }  }{ \cos\theta -\frac { \cos\theta  }{ \sin\theta  }  } $$

$$\frac { \frac { \sin^{ 2 }\theta -1 }{ \sin\theta  }  }{ \frac { \sin\theta \cos\theta -\cos\theta  }{\sin\theta  }  } $$

$$\frac { \sin^{ 2 }\theta -1 }{ \sin\theta  } \cdot \frac { \sin\theta  }{ \sin\theta \cos\theta -\cos\theta  } $$

$$\frac { (\sin^{ 2 }\theta -1) }{ (\cos\theta )(\sin\theta -1) } $$

Now where do I go from here? As far as I can tell, $\sin^{ 2 }\theta -1=-\cos^2\theta $

so this makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right: Now follow through: $${-\cos^2\theta \over {\cos \theta(\sin\theta-1)}}= {\cos\theta \over -(\sin \theta -1)}$$ All you have to do now is reverse the sign on the denominator.

Comment: Now I just feel stupid for missing something so small. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 3):

You've already solved the problem:

$$\begin{align}
\dfrac { (\sin^{ 2 }\theta -1) }{ (\cos\theta )(\sin\theta -1) } &= \dfrac{-\cos^2\theta}{(\cos\theta)(\sin\theta - 1)} \\
&= \dfrac{-\cos\theta}{\sin\theta-1} \\
&= \dfrac{\cos \theta}{-(\sin\theta-1)} \\
&= L.H.S.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{\sin^2\theta-1}{\cos \theta(\sin\theta-1)}=\dfrac{-\cos^2\theta}{\cos \theta(\sin\theta-1)}=\dfrac{-\cos\theta}{\sin\theta-1}=\dfrac{\cos\theta}{1-\sin\theta}$